# Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ = a, $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$ = b. We need to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_nb_1+a_{n-1}b_2+...+a_1b_1}{n}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ = a, $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$ = b. We need to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_nb_1+a_{n-1}b_2+...+a_1b_1}{n}$. 

As far as I get it, the answer is $ab$. 

I've tried this to prove it: as both $a_n$ and $b_n$ have a limit, they also both have a supremum. Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be the supremua. Then by the properties of supremum for any given $е$ there are $k, l$ such that 
$$\frac{a_nb_1+a_{n-1}b_2+...+a_1b_n}{n}<C_1C_2<(a_k+e)(b_l+e)$$
And I feel like there is some tiny step from here to the solution as the above is more or less $ab$, but I just can't get there. Would you mind giving some hints?

Comment: For large $n$, the sum $a_nb_1 + \dotsb + a_1b_n$ consists of three parts. The start, where $a_k$ is close to $a$, but $b_j$ is far away from $b$ (maybe), the middle, where $a_k$ is close to $a$ and $b_j$ close to $b$, and the end where $a_k$ is (maybe) not close to $a$. The start and the end don't grow in length with $n$.

Comment: I think that looking at supremums is a bit in the wrong direction. (Note for instance that the supremum could just be $a_1$ itself, which might not have anything to do with $\lim a_n$.) Instead, use the fact that for any $\epsilon$, all of the $a_n$ except the first few will be between $a-\epsilon$ and $a+\epsilon$, and similarly for $b$. (Here, "the first few" means some finite number of terms depending on $\epsilon$.)

Comment: As this result is a generalisation of the Cesaro mean result (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean), an idea may be to prove the result in the case where $b_n = 1$ for all $n$, and then a generalisation using Daniel Fischer's idea should be a lot easier to see.

Comment: The last $b_1$ in the title is a $b_n$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{2n\to\infty} \frac{a_{2n}b_1+\cdots+a_{n+1}b_n+a_nb_{n+1}+\cdots+a_1b_{2n}}{2n}=$$

$$\lim_{2n\to\infty} \frac{a_{2n}b_1+\cdots+a_{n+1}b_n}{2n} + \frac{a_nb_{n+1}+\cdots+a_1b_{2n}}{2n}=$$

$$\lim_{2n\to\infty} (a+\epsilon(2n))\frac{b_1+\cdots+b_n}{2n}+(b+\epsilon'(2n))\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}{2n}$$

Where $\epsilon, \epsilon'$ each go to zero with $n$.

$$=a\frac{b}{2}+b\frac{a}{2}=ab$$

Using [Cesaro mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean) as Andrew suggests.